# What would be the best way to return a result based on the value of a variable?

Tags: bash

So I have a little script I'm trying to write. It generates a number between two integers, and then returns a result based on that number. I'm trying to decide what the best way to actually write this is. All I can think of is to do if/then/else for every option, so it would look something like this:

```
ROLL=$(shuf -i 1-50 -n 1)
if [ "$ROLL" -eq "1" ];then
echo BLUE
elif [ "$ROLL" -le "8" ];then
echo RED
elif [ "$ROLL" -le "19" ];then
echo GREEN
elif [ "$ROLL" -le "37" ];then
echo PINK
elif [ "$ROLL" -le "49" ];then
echo BROWN
else
echo BLACK
fi
```

Except the working script will have about thirty times as many possible outcomes. The above is just a shortened version of what I'm doing so it's clear what I'm asking. (hopefully clear, anyway)

This works, but it seems like there must be a better way go about it. But the fact that the number and word isn't matched one to one (meaning, 1 = BLUE, but 2-8 are RED, and 38-49 are BROWN, instead of 1=BLUE, 2=RED, 3=BROWN, etc), it seems like it might be difficult.

Is there a different way I should be doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Using arrays with proper range checking:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

colors=( [1]="BLUE" [8]="RED" [19]="GREEN" [37]="PINK" [49]="BROWN" )
indexes=( "${!colors[@]}" )
roll=$((RANDOM % 50 + 1))

result="in range"
(( roll < indexes[0] || roll > indexes[-1] )) && result=

for num in ${result:+"${indexes[@]}"}; do
    (( roll <= num )) && { result="${colors[num]}"; break; }
done

echo "${result:=BLACK}"
```

This checks if the roll falls in the correct range. If it's greater than the last number **OR** lesser than the first number, it outputs `BLACK`.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over a sorted array like

```
COLORS=(
   "1  BLUE"
   "8  RED"
   "19 GREEN"
   # ...
   "50 BLACK"
)

for c in "${COLORS[@]}"; do
    set -- $c
    test "$ROLL" -le $1 || continue
    echo "$2"
    break
done
```

Code uses `50` (which is the highest possible input value) for the `else` branch.  When things are more complex, you can express it differently (e.g. `-` or omit it completely and check `$#`) and adapt the inner check.

Comment: You are missing the `else`, ie the `BLACK` case.